# Bound must be positive when add a list?

Tags: java, random

My categories list doesn't empty but when I call fake product API, it return:`"message": "bound must be positive"`. Maybe the random made these errors? I don't know why. Help me, please!

```java
    @GetMapping("/fake")
    public BaseAPI fakeProducts() {
        BaseAPI baseAPI = new BaseAPI();
        try {
            long totalproducts = productService.getTotalProducts();
            List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Category> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
            Random random = new Random();
            for (long i = totalproducts+1; i <= totalproducts + 10; i++)
            {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setName("Product" +i);
                product.setPrice(prices[random.nextInt(prices.length)]);
                product.setMainImage(images[random.nextInt(images.length)]);
                product.setSize(sizes[random.nextInt(sizes.length)]);
                product.setDisplay(screens[random.nextInt(screens.length)]);
                product.setOperatorSystem(os[random.nextInt(os.length)]);
                product.setFrontCamera(frontCam[random.nextInt(frontCam.length)]);
                product.setBackCamera(backCam[random.nextInt(backCam.length)]);
                product.setCategory(categoryList.get(random.nextInt(categoryList.size())));
                product.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                productList.add(product);
            }
            productService.addListProducts(productList);
            baseAPI.setMessage("success");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            baseAPI.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
        return baseAPI;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I strongly suspect that this message is from the exception, but because you've discarded everything except the message, you've lost a lot of information. I would suggest that a) you set the message to the complete exception detail - just call `toString()`; b) you debug through the code to find out where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: What is BaseAPI? and does that mean that you're making an API call?

Comment: "My categories list doesn't empty" - no, your category list is *definitely* empty. You're creating a new `ArrayList<Category>`, and never adding anything to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

```java
product.setCategory(categoryList.get(random.nextInt(categoryList.size())));
```

Your category list is empty - you never add anything to it. That means you're calling `random.nextInt(0)` which is invalid.

How you fix that is up to you - do you *need* a category in your product? If so, you should create one. Do you need it to be random, or could you use the same category for all your products? If you don't need it to be random, just create a single category and get rid of the list entirely.

Separately, I'd strongly recommend that you change this catch block:

```java
catch (Exception e) {
  baseAPI.setMessage(e.getMessage());
}
```

to call `toString` instead:

```java
catch (Exception e) {
  baseAPI.setMessage(e.toString());
}
```

That way you'll get the full exception stack trace (and exception type), which will give you a lot more information than just the message.